# Sequence of prime numbers in range

Tags: math, clojure

I would like to write a function `prime-seq` to show a list between two numbers, using `from` and `to`.

Here is my code, I think it is if the numbers from the list are true then display them. But I have no idea how to write it, I am very new for this language.

```
(defn is-prime? [n]
  (empty?
    (filter #(= 0 (mod n %)) (range 2 n))))

(defn prime-seq [from to]
  (drop from (take to is-prime?)))
```

the result should be:

```
(prime-seq 1 5)
=> (2 3 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close:

```
(defn is-prime? [n]
  (empty? (filter #(= 0 (mod n %)) (range 2 n))))

(defn prime-seq [from to]
  (filter is-prime? (range from (inc to))))

(prime-seq 1 29)
=> (1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29)
```

This is using `range` generate a sequence of all numbers between `from` and `to` (inclusive), then `filter`ing that list using your `is-prime?` predicate.

As for your `is-prime?` predicate, there are many approaches to determining primeness. As you comment `(mod 1 1) => 0`, so your predicate returns true however 1 isn't a prime number. You can simply add a special case for this in your predicate so that any number less than 2 returns `false`:

```
(defn is-prime? [n]
  (if (< 1 n)
    (empty? (filter #(= 0 (mod n %)) (range 2 n)))
    false))
```

Or slightly more terse using `and`:

```
(defn is-prime? [n]
  (and (< 1 n)
       (not (some #(= 0 (mod n %)) (range 2 n)))))
```

Comment: sorry can I ask another question, I found when I input (is-prime? 1)  it displayed true, how can I change it. thank you

Answer (score 1):

In case people come here for a reasonably fast algorithm for finding prime numbers implemented in Clojure, here's an implementation of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) in Clojure (using JVM arrays):

```
(defn find-primes
 "Finds all prime numbers less than n, returns them sorted in a vector"
  [n]
  (if (< n 2)
    []
    (let [^booleans sieve (boolean-array n false)
          s (-> n Math/sqrt Math/floor int)]
      (loop [p 2]
        (if (> p s)
          (into []
            (remove #(aget sieve %))
            (range 2 n))
          (do
            (when-not (aget sieve p)
              (loop [i (* 2 p)]
                (when (< i n)
                  (aset sieve i true)
                  (recur (+ i p)))))
            (recur (inc p))))))))
```

Example:

```
(find-primes 100)
=> [2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97]
```

And some benchmarking:

```
(require '[criterium.core :as bench])

(bench/bench
  (find-primes 100000))

;Evaluation count : 17940 in 60 samples of 299 calls.
;             Execution time mean : 3.370834 ms
;    Execution time std-deviation : 217.730604 µs
;   Execution time lower quantile : 3.040426 ms ( 2.5%)
;   Execution time upper quantile : 3.792958 ms (97.5%)
;                   Overhead used : 1.755126 ns
```